# difference between present perfect continuous and simple with negative sentences

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

I **have not met** her very often lately   I **have not been meeting** her very often lately.

Is the only difference between these 2 sentences the continuity of the action
the first means a recently finished action and the second an ongoing action

Comment: To me, the second one suggests that the speaker used to meet 'her' at regular intervals, but that lately the meetings have become less frequent.

Comment: what does  the first one mean? I met  her about 2 or 3 times before(but not at regular intervals )  and now it has  gone down to 1or 2 times .

Comment: It suggests to me that the speaker has occasionally met 'her' in the past, probably by chance, but it has happened less often recently. (I don't mean that the two versions _definitely_ mean different things, just that _have been meeting_ is more likely to imply a series of planned meetings.)